# Invert html "contact us" ribbon when directions is rtl

Tags: html, css

I have a "contact us" ribbon that expands on hover. It sits on the right and expands to the left when hovered on (english version, dir=ltr).

```css
:root {
  --color-ribbon-body: #FFD72A;
  --color-ribbon-tail: #FECC30;
  --color-ribbon-crease: #FC9544;
  --color-ribbon-shadow: #AFAFAF;
  --color-ribbon-foreground: #343434;
}

.contactus {
  top: calc(var(--app-header-height) + 50px);
  max-width: var(--app-max-width);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  left: unset;
  top: 50px;
  right: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2);
}

.contactus:after,
.contactus:before,
.contactusbutton:before,
.contactusbutton:after,
.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.contactus:before {
  background: var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 0.2em;
  top: 0.25em;
}

.contactusbutton {
  background-color: var(--color-ribbon-body);
  color: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all 0.75s;
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: 24px;
}

.contactusbutton:hover {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}

.contactusbutton:before {
  border-color: transparent var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent;
  border-width: .33em .99em 0 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.contactusbutton:after {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: .5em 2em 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

.contactus:after,
.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-tail) transparent var(--color-ribbon-tail) var(--color-ribbon-tail);
  border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -2.4em;
  top: 0.5em;
}

.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-shadow) transparent var(--color-ribbon-shadow) var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
  right: -2.3em;
  top: 0.7em;
}

.contactusbutton>svg {
  stroke: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
  display: inline-block;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.contactusbutton:hover>svg {
  stroke-width: 2.0;
}

.contactusbutton>span {
  transition: max-width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 0;
}

.contactusbutton:hover>span {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="contactus">
    <button class="contactusbutton">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-user-plus" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="none" stroke="none" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4" />
                <path d="M3 21v-2a4 4 0 0 1 4 -4h4a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v2" />
                <path d="M16 11h6m-3 -3v6" />
            </svg>
            <span>Contact us</span>
        </button>
  </div>

</body>
```

I need this ribbon to be inverted when direction is rtl so it sits on the left and expands out to the right, with the text being on the left and the svg on the right.

I've tried many different ways but to be honest I'm shooting in the dark here, I'm not really a front-end developer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just want to say that having to hover over things to "discover" what they are is a poor UX; if I'm looking for a way to contact you I don't want to have to hover over random stuff to find where the contact-form (of whatever) is hidden. I'm not playing games, I'm trying to contact you.

Comment: @RobIII oh don't worry about that, it actually also reacts to scrolling or any other interaction with the page from the user, you couldn't miss it even if you tried to... and there is a contact us button that's always visible in navbar and in aside too! This is just some bullshit the client wanted so I obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this add the following styles in your code:

```
.contactus {
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
   left: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2);
   right: unset;
}

.contactusbutton>span {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.contactus span::before{
  display: none;
}


/* Styles for Ribbon and its shadow */

.ribbon {
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color-ribbon-shadow) transparent var(--color-ribbon-shadow) var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
    border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -42px;
    top: 4px;
}

.ribbon:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color-ribbon-tail) transparent var(--color-ribbon-tail) var(--color-ribbon-tail);
    border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -2.4em;
    top: 0.5em;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-ribbon-body: #FFD72A;
  --color-ribbon-tail: #FECC30;
  --color-ribbon-crease: #FC9544;
  --color-ribbon-shadow: #AFAFAF;
  --color-ribbon-foreground: #343434;
}

.contactus {
  top: calc(var(--app-header-height) + 50px);
  max-width: var(--app-max-width);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  left: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2);
  right: unset;
}

.contactus:before,
.contactusbutton:before,
.contactusbutton:after,
.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.contactus:before {
  background: var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 0.2em;
  top: 0.25em;
}

.ribbon {
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color-ribbon-shadow) transparent var(--color-ribbon-shadow) var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
    border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -42px;
    top: 4px;
}

.ribbon:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--color-ribbon-tail) transparent var(--color-ribbon-tail) var(--color-ribbon-tail);
    border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
    z-index: -1;
    right: -2.4em;
    top: 0.5em;
}

.contactusbutton {
  background-color: var(--color-ribbon-body);
  color: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: all 0.75s;
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: 24px;
}

.contactusbutton:hover {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}

.contactusbutton:before {
  border-color: transparent var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent;
  border-width: .33em .99em 0 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.contactusbutton:after {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: .5em 2em 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-tail) transparent var(--color-ribbon-tail) var(--color-ribbon-tail);
  border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -2.4em;
  top: 0.5em;
}

.contactusbutton>span:before {
  border-color: var(--color-ribbon-shadow) transparent var(--color-ribbon-shadow) var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
  right: -2.3em;
  top: 0.7em;
}

.contactusbutton>svg {
  stroke: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
  display: inline-block;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.contactusbutton:hover>svg {
  stroke-width: 2.0;
}

.contactusbutton>span {
  transition: max-width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.contactusbutton:hover>span {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.contactus span::before{
    display: none;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="contactus">
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
  <button class="contactusbutton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-user-plus" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="none" stroke="none" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
      <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4" />
      <path d="M3 21v-2a4 4 0 0 1 4 -4h4a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v2" />
      <path d="M16 11h6m-3 -3v6" />
    </svg>
    <span>Contact us</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can the black box be fixed? The tail usually has its own shadow that I couldn't make appear correctly here, but I would like it to appear on the left version too as it is on the right

Comment: Try my code. I had removed the shadow and scrolling too.

Comment: @MLquest The tail has its own shadow now. You can have a look at the updated code. To do this edit HTML and CSS files with ribbon element.

Comment: @ShaliniGandhi I'm immensely thankful for your  assistance. You have made my life so much easier! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes I have made:

```
.contactus {
    top: calc(var(--app-header-height) + 50px);
    max-width: var(--app-max-width);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: fixed;
    left: unset;
    top: 50px;
    /* right: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2); */
    left: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2);
    /* Removing the right property and positioning to the left with the left property */
}

.contactus span{
    transform: scale(-1,1);
    /* Transforming the text so that it's orientation remains the same */
}

.contactus span::before{
    display: none;
    /* a dark box and scrollbar appears after text transformation. So hiding them */
}

.contactus {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    /* Transforming the whole ribbon */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        :root {
            --color-ribbon-body: #FFD72A;
            --color-ribbon-tail: #FECC30;
            --color-ribbon-crease: #FC9544;
            --color-ribbon-shadow: #AFAFAF;
            --color-ribbon-foreground: #343434;
        }

        .contactus {
            top: calc(var(--app-header-height) + 50px);
            max-width: var(--app-max-width);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            position: fixed;
            left: unset;
            top: 50px;
            /* right: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2); */
            left: calc((100vw - 300px) / 2);
        }

        .contactus:after,
        .contactus:before,
        .contactusbutton:before,
        .contactusbutton:after,
        .contactusbutton>span:before {
            border-style: solid;
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
        }

        .contactus:before {
            background: var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
            border: none;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -2;
            left: 0.2em;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

        .contactusbutton {
            background-color: var(--color-ribbon-body);
            color: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
            padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
            position: relative;
            font-weight: 500;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            float: right;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            transition: all 0.75s;
            overflow-x: visible;
            height: 24px;
        }

        .contactusbutton:hover {
            padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
        }

        .contactusbutton:before {
            border-color: transparent var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent;
            border-width: .33em .99em 0 0;
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }

        .contactusbutton:after {
            border-color: var(--color-ribbon-crease) transparent transparent transparent;
            border-width: .5em 2em 0 0;
            top: 100%;
            right: 0;
        }

        .contactus:after,
        .contactusbutton>span:before {
            border-color: var(--color-ribbon-tail) transparent var(--color-ribbon-tail) var(--color-ribbon-tail);
            border-width: 1.1em 1em 1.1em 3em;
            z-index: -1;
            right: -2.4em;
            top: 0.5em;
        }

        .contactusbutton>span:before {
          border-color: var(--color-ribbon-shadow) transparent var(--color-ribbon-shadow) var(--color-ribbon-shadow);
          right: -2.3em;
          top: 0.7em;
        }

        .contactusbutton>svg {
            stroke: var(--color-ribbon-foreground);
            display: inline-block;
            stroke-width: 1.5;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
        }

        .contactusbutton:hover>svg {
            stroke-width: 2.0;
        }

        .contactusbutton>span {
            transition: max-width 1s;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            line-height: 150%;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: left;
            height: inherit;
            max-width: 0;
        }

        .contactusbutton:hover>span {
            max-width: 300px;
        }

        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

        .contactus span{
            transform: scale(-1,1);
        }

        .contactus span::before{
            display: none;
        }

        .contactus {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
            -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
            filter: fliph; /*IE*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="contactus">
        <button class="contactusbutton">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-user-plus" width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="none" stroke="none" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                <circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4" />
                <path d="M3 21v-2a4 4 0 0 1 4 -4h4a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v2" />
                <path d="M16 11h6m-3 -3v6" />
            </svg>
            <span class="my-span">Contact us</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```